# JavaScript isn't reading correctly a static json file

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have been working on a project, where I have to get data from a database with its own server. For that, I have used Django as a tool to combine both backend and frontend.
Also, I created a function that connects python to odbc so I can get the information from the database. My logic was that I want to convert all the information into a JSON file so that javascript (frontend) would have access to it to convert it into graphs.
To make myself more clear, here are the main components:

- views.py

```
    def get_name(request):
        # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
            form = TextForm(request.POST)
            # check whether it's valid:
            if form.is_valid():
                # From this we get the result of POST method
                date = form.cleaned_data['date']
                splitdate = date.split(sep='-')
                # Here we call the class created in Functions.py
                x = GetData(int(splitdate[2]), int(splitdate[1]), int(splitdate[0]))
                x.getInfo()
                context = {
                    'text': date,
                    'form': form,
                }
                return render(request, 'index.html', context)
        # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
        else:
            form = TextForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

- forms.py

```
class TextForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), label=False)
```

HTML file

```
<div class="row row-cols-md-auto g-lg-3">

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form  action = '#' method="POST" id="form">
                        <label for="input_date">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form }}
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
                            </label>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the part where javascript tries to connect to the JSON file

```
fetch('static/example.json')
            .then((res) => {
                res.json();
                console.log(res);
            })
```

[image: the image gives an idea about my directory]

so after my function in views.py dumps the data into my JSON file and replace the old one, my js doesn't seem to read it at all, it's like stuck on reading on an old version, that doesn't even exist anymore, how is it possible, and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean it does load, but only an older version of your .json file? Then it is probably cached. Try adding a timestamp to your json request.

Comment: how can I do it ?

Comment: Try changing your fetch to `fetch('static/example.json?t=' + Date.now())`